# Re-use a calculated field value in the same row - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper, correlated-subquery

What I am trying to do is writing a query that gives the following output:

[image: Output of query]

The day value for an accountnumber is a calculated field that calculates a number with information that is currently in the DB. Then for day +1 I need to begin my calculation with the day value. But how can I pass this value so that I can use it for my calculation in day +1? How can I do this? They don't like pl sql at my workplace so that's the worst case scenario.

Currently I wrote the query to get information for all 16 accounts just for one day:

```
 select OBforeachaccount.accountnumber accountnumbers, (OBforeachaccount.OB - NVL(IDforeachaccount.sumamounts,0) - NVL(paymentsforeachaccount.sumpayments,0)) as day1, day1+5 as day2
    from
    --ophalen van CB day -1
    (select account_id accountnumber,cal_date,cb_amount_default OB from fillinggaps g, dim_date d
    where g.balance_date = d.cal_date and
    d.cal_date = TO_CHAR(sysdate -1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
    order by account_id, cal_date) OBforeachaccount,

    (select a.id accountnumber, cal_date, sum(AMOUNT_USD) sumamounts
    from fact_id_transaction i, dim_date d, dim_account a
    where i.value_date_id = d.id and 
    i.account_id  = a.id and 
    d.cal_date = TO_CHAR(sysdate -1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
    --future: add filter based on the account number
    group by a.id, cal_date
    order by a.id,cal_date) IDforeachaccount,

    (select ordering_account_id accountnumber,cal_date, sum(instructed_amount_default) sumpayments
    from fact_payment p, dim_date d
    where 
    p.value_date_id = d.id and
    d.cal_date = TO_CHAR(sysdate -1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
    group by ordering_account_id, cal_date
    order by ordering_account_id, cal_date) paymentsforeachaccount
    where 
    OBforeachaccount.accountnumber = IDforeachaccount.accountnumber(+) and
    OBforeachaccount.accountnumber = paymentsforeachaccount.accountnumber(+)
```

Thanks for your advice guys

Comment: Which version and release of Oracle are you using? 11gR2?

Comment: I'm using version 11G

Answer (score 0):

I suggesting using an inline view to get the account number and day one value, and then in a containing query just reference the day one value as needed in additional columns.

In a pseudo query:

```
select
    account_number,
    day1,
    day1+x day2,
    day1+y day3
from
    (select
        account_number,
        intensive_calculation day1
    from
        tables
    where
        something = something);
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to do this with the inline view. It works but It gives some serious performance issues. My query has a loadingtime of 8 seconds. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The inline view should not really affect performance, the Oracle optimizer will handle it very well. Do you have any joins against the inline view? I would look at the performance of the inner query, check the explain plan.